# Moving SQL record up or down Based on the number inserted or removed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select list of records that have a number 1-10. 
The `value` for each `<option>` is the id from the record on the database and the `text` is another column value --- `numToDo`. (see below)

```
<select>
<option value="101">1</option>
<option value="102">2</option>
<option value="103">3</option>
<option value="104">4</option>
<option value="105">5</option>
...
</select>
```

I want to allow the user to add/remove and readjust items from the list, but I want the list to remain in order if 1-10. In other words if the person thinks record `105` should be completed before 102 I would like the current `2-(102)` to be moved down and have the rest of those records 104,105 etc to change as well. 
in other words have it look like this:

```
<select>
<option value="101">1</option>
<option value="105">2</option>
<option value="102">3</option>
<option value="103">4</option>
<option value="104">5</option>
....
```

There are only ever 10 items or less listed at a time, and when they get completed the `numToDo` for the record becomes a 0 which gets moved out of the list and the numbers should be moved up as well, but if I can just get help with the first part I mentioned I can figure the rest out on my own.

I'm assuming this would be a query on the database end where it takes in the ID and the new number and updates the current row and then updates the rest based on the number affected? I don't really work on SQL so i'm not really sure if this can be done.

Comment: Which RDBMS? Also I didn't understand your input. Is it an xml file which you parse and then you have to update the table?

Comment: You've explained the part of the logic very well. I'm not understanding the context, though. How are you interfacing the database?

Comment: I use SQL Server Manager, and no this is a simple php form, where the user selected a record, and I run a query where it gets the selected option value and the number they want the item to be and send it along using JS and then php. What I was doing before was just updating the selected row, but then I had two 2s  or 3s and began missing numbers from my 1-10 numbered list. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: So if you find an algorithm, then you're good? Or do you want to update the database, and then re-select the new values?

Comment: i guess in my case i would need to update the database. When the query is completed I do a refresh function which reloads the page to the exact spot of the page. above my php form I am already selecting the items in order and then displaying them so reelecting wouldn't be necessary in the db query

Answer (score 0):

Use a record you can sort on, and when you move a record to a new spot, just ensure that the record sorting places it at the right spot. If you eg have this ordering

```
          Sorting 
Record#    order
  101        1
  102        2
  103        3
  104        4
  105        5
```

you can move record `105` to the second spot by only updating one sorting key like this.

```
          Sorting 
Record#    order
  101        1
  105        1.5   < average of record 101 and 102's Sorting key
  102        2
  103        3
  104        4
```

Comment: this is very helpful but what if the number begin removed is 104 not 105, wouldn't I just have a 1.5 and not a 4 in the sorting order? I see what you mean, and I get the correct placement but the unfortunate part is I also display the Sorting number its actually a column on my table.